# I want to extract movie scripts from www.imsdb.com/scripts/*.html

Tags: html, parsing, text, save, extract

There are scripts references on https://imsdb.com/all-scripts.html. The scripts themselves are on [www.imsdb.com/scripts/*.html](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/*.html)

I managed to print the [www.imsdb.com/scripts/Joker.html](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Joker.html) all text. But I need to get the pure texts of all scripts. And finally write it in one or several word files.

Here is easy initial code:

```
url = "https://imsdb.com/scripts/Joker.html"
con = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(con,'html.parser')
texts = soup.get_text()
print(texts)
```

Please any recommendations for extraction of all scripts from [www.imsdb.com/scripts/*.html](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/*.html) ?

Comment: Add snippet to your question.

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by adding snippet ?